# IOS 7 scrolling to particular row making some part of tableview blank

Tags: ios7

I have screen as shown in below figure[image]

It is showing sessions grouped by time for a particular date. 
Top one is a horizontal tableview which displays date.
Bottom one is a vertical tableview showing sessions grouped by time.
On clicking "Now" button, we are scrolling to
1.Current date and reloading vertical tableview data
2.we are scrolling to  section which shows current ongoing sessions.
For that I set row and section.

int row=[self getCurrentTimeRow];
        [self.tableView_sessionList reloadData];
 [self.tableView_sessionList scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];});

It scrolls but results in weird behaviour.Top half tableview is blank.
Bottom half showing rows.
[image]

Problem occurs on reloading tableview and scrolling to a particular row.
This issue occurs only on ios7.
Same code working fine on IOS8.

Any help will be appreciated.